# Tuple bool value does not change

Tags: c++, class, tuples

I have a small problem to change the tuple bool value. Does anyone know how the bool value is not changed? The function `setState()` finds the searched key! Many thanks for your help!

**keyManager.h**

```
class keyManager
{
private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, bool>> productKeys;

public:
    void addProductKey(std::string key);
    std::tuple<std::string, bool> getProductKey(int index);
    void setState(std::string searchKey, bool state);


    keyManager();
    ~keyManager();
};
```

**keyManager.cpp**

```
void keyManager::addProductKey(std::string key)
{
    productKeys.emplace_back(key, false);
}

std::tuple<std::string, bool> keyManager::getProductKey(int index)
{
    return productKeys[index];
}

void keyManager::setState(std::string searchKey, bool state)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < productKeys.size(); x++)
    {
        auto t = productKeys[x];
        if (std::get<std::string>(t) == searchKey)
        {
            std::get<bool>(t) = state;
        }
    }
}
```

**main()**

```
keyManager kManager;
kManager.addProductKey(KEY_1);

kManager.setState(KEY_1, true);

auto t = kManager.getProductKey(0);
std::cout << std::get<bool>(t) << std::endl;
```

**Output:** 0

The program is executed without errors, so I assume that I have a mistake somewhere happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `keyManager::setState` the line

```
auto t = productKeys[x];
```

makes a copy, use

```
auto& t = productKeys[x];
```

instead to get a reference to `productKeys[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

This line will copy your `tuple`

```
auto t = productKeys[x];
```

Switch to a reference

```
auto& t = productKeys[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
auto t = productKeys[x];
```

`t` is deduced to be of type `std::tuple<std::string, bool>` and the `=` triggers the copy asssignment operator of the tuple which actually makes `t` a **copy** of `productKeys[x]`.

All the operation you perform on `t` affect only `t`.
You should force the compiler to deduce `t` as a reference (with type `std::tuple<std::string, bool>&`) as in the following:

```
auto& t = productKeys[x];
```